# Is it possible to generate a tag cloud from another field?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WP as an image library, basically by just directly querying the media as 'attachment'. Everything on my site works great. I'm just looking for an enhancement here, but I'm not sure if it's possible. Keywords for images (for search purposes) are in the 'captions' field of every image. I display them right now exploded with commas removed. I would *love* it if there was a way to grab *all* the terms in *all* the images and create a weighted tag cloud. But right now it looks like I can only create the tag cloud using taxonomy terms that images are assigned to (I created a custom taxonomy for that).

So I'm basically just wondering if there's a way to create this tag cloud by accessing the caption field, exploding it out, and then displaying in a weighted, hierarchical manner.

Comment: Yes, this does sound possible.  You would have to write some code that collects that information and presents it to the tag cloud properly.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it requires writing some code. Would you be able to put me on the correct path for figuring out what that code should be?

Comment: You can check out https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_tag_cloud/ for a possible WP option.